# How should I add GeoIP module to nginx?

Tags: nginx, centos, geoip

I'm using nginx version 1.8 on a centos 6.7 server but when using nginx -V command , I can't see geoip_module there . How can I add it to nginx ?

Comment: sorry for the external link, but I think you can use this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html

Comment: thanks but nothing about adding the module to nginx there

Comment: This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-http_geoip_module configuration parameter. http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_166/

Comment: Where did you get nginx from?

Answer (score 3):

Nginx doesn't have "modules" in apache sense, it has to be recompiled with the module you need included during ./configure.

It's actually pretty easy - just follow this steps:

1. Install prerequisites for building nginx by using the following commands:

   `yum group install "Development Tools"`

   `yum install gcc gd-devel GeoIP-devel`
2. Download latest nginx source from http://nginx.org/en/download.html

   `wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.15.7.tar.gz`
3. Unpack it & enter the source tree directory

   `tar xzfv nginx-1.15.7.tar.gz && cd nginx-1.15.7`
4. Get the configuration arguments of your installed nginx (by running `nginx -V`), add the `--with-http_geoip_module` option to them or just configure with the following command:

   `./configure --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-pcre --with-file-aio --without-http_scgi_module --without-http_uwsgi_module --without-http_fastcgi_module --user=nginx --group=nginx --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-http_image_filter_module --with-cc-opt="-march=native -mtune=native -O2 -pipe"  --with-sha1-asm --with-zlib-asm=pentiumpro --with-md5-asm --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module  --with-http_v2_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_geoip_module`

   [options are explained here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-compile-nginx-from-source-on-a-centos-6-4-x64-vps)
5. `make && make install`
6. Now you have the GeoIP support in your nginx. To use it, download and unpack databases from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

   `curl http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz | gzip -d - > /etc/nginx/GeoIP.dat`

   `curl http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz | gzip -d - > /etc/nginx/GeoLiteCity.dat`
7. Add them to the **http** section of your *nginx config file*:

   `geoip_country  /etc/nginx/GeoIP.dat;`

   `geoip_city     /etc/nginx/GeoLiteCity.dat;`
8. And finally define headers, which will contain the GeoIP information in the **server** section of your *nginx config fil*e:

   `proxy_set_header GEOIP_REGION $geoip_region;`

   `proxy_set_header GEOIP_REGION_NAME $geoip_region_name;`

   `proxy_set_header GEOIP_CITY $geoip_city;`

   `proxy_set_header GEOIP_AREA_CODE $geoip_area_code;`

   `proxy_set_header GEOIP_LATITUDE $geoip_latitude;`

   `proxy_set_header GEOIP_LONGITUDE $geoip_longitude;`

   `proxy_set_header GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE $geoip_postal_code;`

Comment: If nginx is already installed and running and one follows your steps above, does this simply overwrite existing install? Config losses?

Comment: @Chris nope, it only overwrites nginx binariesm. Make sure you use exact configuration directives from your system in step 4 though

Answer (score 1):

1. create a new file , /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

if your system version is centos 7.x ,you need change it in the 'baseurl'

2. then , `yum install nginx-module-geoip`

you got it